# Image not showing up in View, in a component. This image does show up within a different component View

Tags: react-native, image, components

The image will not show up in the component view.  It does show up in a different component view.  I am not sure the difference.  There is a test property that outputs 'works' to the console to verify the Image component is being read.  It does log to the console. I have tried setting zIndex to 0, 1, 5. I have also removed everything in the return statement and left only the Image.  The image can be placed in an adjacent component view and will show up. Assistance is appreciated.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {StyleE} from '../../00_sharedComponents/InputA/styles';
import {Image} from 'react-native-svg';


const InputA = props => {
  const [text1, onChangeText1] = useState('');
  const [showPass, changeShowPass] = useState(props.secure);

  if (props.secure == false) {
    return (
      <View style={[StyleE.mainContainer, StyleE.shadowProp]}>
        <TextInput
          style={StyleE.inputField}
          onChangeText={value => onChangeText1(value)}
          placeholder={props.ph}
          placeholderTextColor={'#9a9a9a'}
          value={text1}
          secureTextEntry={props.secure}
        />
      </View>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={[StyleE.mainContainer, StyleE.shadowProp]}>
        <Image
          test={console.log('works')}
          source={require('../../00_sharedAssets/login/showpass.png')}
          style={{
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            backgroundColor: 'white',
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
};

export {InputA};


//-----------------------------------------------------
//  ../../00_sharedComponents/InputA/styles
/*
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const StyleE = StyleSheet.create({
  shadowProp: {
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20)',
    textShadowOffset: {width: 1, height: 40},
    textShadowRadius: 1,
    elevation: 2,
  },
  mainContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '100%',
    height: 60,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
    borderRadius: 8,
    backgroundColor: '#444444',
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  inputField: {
    //borderWidth: 1,
    //borderColor: '#000',
    borderRadius: 8,
    height: 48,
    padding: 10,
    paddingLeft: 15,
    fontSize: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    color: '#000000',
  },
  passWord:{
    width: '75%',
  },
  passImageStyles: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
});

export {StyleE};

*/
```

```
// 
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleE} from './styles';
import {Image, Text, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import {InputA} from '../../../00_sharedComponents/InputB/index.js';
import {LoginButtonGroup} from '../../../00_sharedComponents/LoginButtonGroup/index.js';
import {LoginWithGroup} from '../../../00_sharedComponents/LoginWithGroup/index.js';


const MyText = ({props}) => {
  return (
    <View style={StyleE.mainView}>
      <Text style={[StyleE.text, StyleE.shadowProp]}>
        Home Manager {props.login}
      </Text>
      <Image
        source={require('../../../00_sharedAssets/login/LoginScreenImage.png')}
        style={StyleE.primaryImageStyles}
      />
      <View style={StyleE.loginContainer}>
        <Text style={StyleE.signIn}>Sign In</Text>
        <InputA secure={false} ph={'Username'} />
        <InputA secure={true} ph={'Password'} />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={StyleE.forgotPassOpacity}
          onPress={() => Alert.alert('Password Needed!')}>
          <Text style={StyleE.forgotPassText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <LoginButtonGroup />
        <LoginWithGroup />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export {MyText};


// where I am rendering InputA
// D:\00 Development\Phone React Native Apps\
// Home_Manager\src\00_sharedScreens\auth\Login\index.js

import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleE} from './styles';
import {Image, Text, View, Alert, TouchableOpacity, } from 'react-native';
import {InputA} from '../../../00_sharedComponents/InputB/index.js';
import {LoginButtonGroup} from '../../../00_sharedComponents/LoginButtonGroup/index.js';
import {LoginWithGroup} from '../../../00_sharedComponents/LoginWithGroup/index.js';


const MyText = ({props}) => {
  return (
    <View style={StyleE.mainView}>
      <Text style={[StyleE.text, StyleE.shadowProp]}>
        Home Manager {props.login}
      </Text>
      <Image
        source={require('../../../00_sharedAssets/login/LoginScreenImage.png')}
        style={StyleE.primaryImageStyles}
      />
      <View style={StyleE.loginContainer}>
        <Text style={StyleE.signIn}>Sign In</Text>
        <InputA secure={false} ph={'Username'} />         
        <InputA secure={true} ph={'Password'} />          
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={StyleE.forgotPassOpacity}
          onPress={() => Alert.alert('Password Needed!')}>
          <Text style={StyleE.forgotPassText}>Forgot Password?</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <LoginButtonGroup />
        <LoginWithGroup />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export {MyText};

// The style sheet for the login page.
// './styles'

import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const StyleE = StyleSheet.create({
  mainView: {
    flex: 1,
    //backgroundColor: 'green',
  },
  text: {
    color: '#000',
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 800,
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  primaryImageStyles: {
    resizeMode: 'contain',
    width: '100%',
    marginTop: 10,
    height: '35%',
    //backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
  loginContainer: {
    width: '75%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    //backgroundColor: 'yellow',
  },
  signIn: {
    color: '#000',
    marginBottom: 5,
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: '800',
  },
  forgotPassOpacity: {
    //backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    height: 20,
    marginBottom: 40,
    width: '50%',
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    justifyContent: 'center', 
  }, 
  forgotPassText: {
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    color: '#3974D5',
  },
  shadowProp: {
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.20)',
    textShadowOffset: {width: 2, height: 4},
    textShadowRadius: 1,
    elevation: 3,
  },
});

export {StyleE};
```

Tried setting size, zIndex, adding to another view in another component.  another view, Image showed up. Tried removing all elements except the image from the component and it still did not show up.

Comment: Is the background color of white showing up? or is the Image component is totally being ignored?

Comment: It is being completely ignored.. Nothing shows up.  However it does run the console log indicating that it is moving through the image component.

Comment: I see there is nothing wrong with your codes, could you please share the codes where you are rendering the component (InputA).

Comment: I was able to copy the code from InputA that renders the pass box and paste it within the login with group.  The image and pass input text showed up.  this is a group of touchable opacity images.

Comment: Also I edited my code to include the requested code.  Thank you for looking at it.

Comment: Could you please share the image you are using? also could you try with a different image, it's possible that the image you are trying to render might contains pure white color, and the styling you are using can make it look hidden.

Comment: I tried your codes in my app, and they are working fine with a dummy image, so, might be a problem with the image you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance.  I have found the error.  It is as follows:
import {Image} from 'react-native-svg';

Should have been:
import {View, TextInput, Image} from 'react-native';

Issue was importing Image for .svg but using a .png image.